# WGET only certain type of files no working as expected

Tags: regex, bash, wget

I'm using trying to download data from this web page:

https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/Ancillary/Attitude-Ephemeris/2019/001/

only those files with the regular pattern *.002

I'm using the following command:

```
wget -r -l1 --no-parent '-A ".002"'  https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/Ancillary/Attitude-Ephemeris/2019/001/
```

but it only downloads a file index.html.

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem. There was an error in the syntax.

The following cmd is the correct one.

```
wget -P /home/test/ -r -l1 -A '*002' https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/Ancillary/Attitude-Ephemeris/2019/002/
```